# Receiving TypeError: n.getChildContext is not a function with shallowWithIntl

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, jestjs, enzyme, react-intl

I started a project a few weeks ago with a react frontend and ruby backend with my coworkers. After a few code reviews, the comments about have an un-internationalized application have caught back up to us. We have an internationalized backend using an i18n gem, but were told the standard for react was to use react-intl as the frontend internationalization package. **I just finished coding-up the internationalization, testing it with a couple languages to ensure it works properly. On the topic of testing, I started running into an issue which I've been banging my head against a wall with.** **I keep receiving this error: n.getChildContext is not a function.** I'm using the package [enzyme-react-intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-react-intl). To test whether or not this works, I decided to only start with taking a snapshot of my components (both functional and class-based). An example of one of my tests is below along with the test suite failure I received. All of my test suites with **shallowWithIntl** and **mountWithIntl** fail. I should note that I am running my tests with the command: 'yarn jest -u'. From all of the searches and api docs I have read I'm not making any *apparent* mistakes, but would appreciate any help to an answer.

**Here is an example test:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { loadTranslation, shallowWithIntl } from 'enzyme-react-intl';
import Header from '../components/Header/Header';
loadTranslation("./app/javascript/translations/en-US.json");

describe('Parent header rendering', () => {
     const shallowHeader = shallowWithIntl(<Header />);
     it('matches the snapshot', () => {
         expect(shallowHeader).toMatchSnapshot();
     });
});
```

**The Test Suite Error I receive.**

FAIL  app/javascript/**tests**/Header.test.jsx
  ● Parent header rendering › encountered a declaration exception

```
TypeError: n.getChildContext is not a function

   5 | 
   6 | describe('Parent header rendering', () => {
>  7 |     const shallowHeader = shallowWithIntl(<Header />);
     |                           ^
   8 |     it('matches the snapshot', () => {
   9 |         expect(shallowHeader).toMatchSnapshot();
  10 |     });

  at _enzyme (node_modules/enzyme-react-intl/lib/webpack:/enzyme-react-intl/src/index.js:47:12)
  at Suite.<anonymous> (app/javascript/__tests__/Header.test.jsx:7:27)
  at Object.describe (app/javascript/__tests__/Header.test.jsx:6:1)
```

I'm a bit of a react/jest/enzyme noob as it stands and want to learn so any pointers and critiques are greatly appreciated no matter how much they eat at my soul.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Apparently, getChildContext is deprecated in react; refer to https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/issues/217. The package I was using still uses getChildContext--eg. https://github.com/joetidee/enzyme-react-intl/blob/master/src/index.js#L47

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of working with the enzyme-react-intl package which is currently deprecated with the getChildContext method, reference the helper functions in the react-intl readme which are up-to-date; [link to testing with enzyme](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/docs/Testing-with-React-Intl.md#enzyme). The code is written in typescript, and to change to js/jsx only a small edit was required. Code is below. Hope this helps. Don't forget to comment the source from the react-intl repo.

```
import React from 'react';
import {IntlProvider} from 'react-intl';
import {mount, shallow} from 'enzyme';

// You can pass your messages to the IntlProvider. Optional: remove if unneeded.
const messages = require('./translations/en-US.json'); // en-US.json
const defaultLocale = 'en-US';
const locale = defaultLocale;

export function mountWithIntl(node) {
  return mount(node, {
    wrappingComponent: IntlProvider,
    wrappingComponentProps: {
      locale,
      defaultLocale,
      messages,
   },
  });
}

  export function shallowWithIntl(node) {
   return shallow(node, {
     wrappingComponent: IntlProvider,
     wrappingComponentProps: {
      locale,
      defaultLocale,
      messages,
     },
  });
}
```

Comment: I added: .dive().dive() onto my shallowWithIntl(node) method in order to access the instance of components I was shallowing.